# Stata: store regression coefficients in a csv file

Tags: stata, export-to-csv

I would like to save regression coefficients in order to plot them in a different software (pgfplots under LaTeX, see this [example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113241/pgfplots-grouped-bar-chart-from-file)).

More specifically, I'm trying to plot bars for the estimated coefficients on a factor variable, e.g.:

```
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r14/cholesterol.dta, clear
reg chol i.agegrp
```

I would like to store each age group and the associated regression coefficient in a .csv file, so that I could plot them in a bar chart using pgfplot.
If possible, I would even like the set of coefficients saved to be limited to those of the factor variable, here `i.agegrp` (and not include other coefficients, such as `_cons`).

I saw the option `text` for outreg2 but didn't manage to get a flat file. Is there any other solution?

Comment: If you want to output a "clean" file, ready to be used by another software, I suggest `postfile`ing yor results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ssc install estout`

and there you go

```
reg y x

eststo mycoeftable
## that saves your coefficients for later use

esttab mycoeftable using "C:/table.csv"
```

look at the documentation for more detailed options http://repec.org/bocode/e/estout/